# liveData with coroutines only trigger first time

Tags: android, coroutine

I have a usecase:

1. Open app + disable network -> display error
2. Exit app, then enable network, then open app again

Expected: app load data

Actual: app display error that meaning state error cached, liveData is not emit

Repository class

```
    class CategoryRepository(
    private val api: ApiService,
    private val dao: CategoryDao
) {
    val categories: LiveData<Resource<List<Category>>> = liveData {
        emit(Resource.loading(null))

        try {
            val data = api.getCategories().result
            dao.insert(data)

            emit(Resource.success(data))
        } catch (e: Exception) {

            val data = dao.getCategories().value

            if (!data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                emit(Resource.success(data))
            } else {
                val ex = handleException(e)
                emit(Resource.error(ex, null))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel class

```
class CategoryListViewModel(
    private val repository: CategoryRepository
): ViewModel() {

    val categories = repository.categories
}
```

Fragment class where LiveDate obsever

```
viewModel.apply {
            categories.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                // live data only trigger first time, when exit app then open again, live data not trigger
            })
        }
```

can you help me explain why live data not trigger in this usecase and how to fix? Thankyou so much

**Update**

I have resolved the above problem by replace `val categories` by `func categories()` at repository class. However, I don't understand and can't explain why it works properly with `func` but not `val`.

Comment: do you kill the app or not?

Comment: I exit app (press button back) and I debug and sure that Fragment(Activity) is destroyed, ViewModel is cleared. But I not kill app from task list.

Comment: I try exit app and if I kill app from task list or clear app cache then open app again, app load data success. why? I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

Why does this happen? This happens because your `ViewModel` has not been killed yet. The `ViewModel` on `cleared()` is called when the `Fragment` is destroyed. In your case your app is not killed and `LiveData` would just emit the latest event already set. I don't think this is a case to use `liveData` builder. Just execute the method in the `ViewModel` when your Fragment gets in `onResume()`:

```
override fun onResume(){
  viewModel.checkData()
  super.onResume()
}
```

```
// in the viewmodel
fun checkData(){
   _yourMutableLiveData.value = Resource.loading(null)

        try {
            val data = repository.getCategories()
            repository.insert(data)

            _yourMutableLiveData.value = Resource.success(data)
        } catch (e: Exception) {

            val data = repository.getCategories()

            if (!data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                _yourMutableLiveData.value = Resource.success(data)
            } else {
                val ex = handleException(e)
                _yourMutableLiveData.value = Resource.error(ex,null)
            }
        }
}
```

Not sure if that would work, but you can try to add the listener directly in `onResume()` but careful with the instantiation of the `ViewModel`.

Small advice, if you don't need a value like in `Resource.loading(null)` just use a `sealed class` with `object`

UPDATE
Regarding your question that you ask why it works with a function and not with a variable, if you call that method in `onResume` it will get executed again. That's the difference. Check the `Fragment` or `Activity` lifecycle before jumping to the `ViewModel` stuff.

Comment: I exit app (press button back) and I debug and sure that Fragment(Activity) is destroyed, ViewModel is cleared. But I not kill app from task list.

Comment: I try exit app and if I kill app from task list or clear app cache then open app again, app load data success. why? I don't understand.

Comment: Because `onCleared` doesn't get called if the app is `onPause`, it get's called only if you kill the app which would call `onDestroy`

Comment: I press button back to exit app. So I sure that activity called `onDestroy` and viewmodel called `onCleared`

Comment: No. If you press back the `onDestroy` doesn't get called. `onDestroy` get's called if you clear the app from the memory

Comment: Maybe you mistake at activity life-cycle. You can log at onDestroy() and press back to see result as me said. And from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) still said "When the user presses the Back button, the current activity is popped from the top of the stack (the activity is destroyed)".

Comment: I updated question and resolved the problem. You can see above and I still have a another question

Comment: I will agree with your answer if activity was not destroyed and view model was not cleared. But I sure that activity destroyed and view model cleared.

Comment: You mean when you press back?

Comment: Exactly, when I press back, I sure activity destroyed and view model cleared.